# IIS 7.5, Windows 7 Professional and MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, iis-7.5

I'm trying to get one of my MVC4 apps to load but having a hard time. This is on a local dev environment running Windows 7 Pro SP1, IIS 7.5, VS2015, .NET 4.6.1 as the target .NET version and MVC4. On this particular app I'm getting HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden. I have other MVC apps running in the same AppPool and those load correctly. Without having to turn on directory browsing in IIS, which I don't want to do. In the system.webServer section of my web.config I have

`<remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />`

but even when I remove the above code block I'm still getting the 403.14 error.
I have tried running:

`%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir`

but that didn't fix things. I also tried the hotfix that microsoft has for the ExtensionlessUrlHandler but that didn't work either. I tried setting `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"` which didn't work either and I don't want to enable that in production. I also tried adding the UrlRoutingModule-4.0 as below but that didn't fix the issue either.

`<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    <remove name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" />
    <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>`

My RouteConfig doesn't change anything with the {id}.

I made sure that .NET 4.6.1 was installed as well as .NET Extensibility. I compared the configuration in IIS between the working app and the non working app and didn't see any glaring differences. I also compared the folder permissions.

Has anyone seen an issue like this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the way home I started to think about all the things that I compared and realized that one thing I did not compare were the actual directories and files in the root directory of the web app. Upon comparing I came across a file named `PrecompiledApp.config` in the root directory of the app I could not get to load that wasn't in the root directory of the other apps that work. Once I removed the file the app loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help.

```
1.Check Directory Browsing of your website if it is enable or not.
   Just Click your deployed website and double click Directory browsing tab.
2.Check project framework in application pool, it must be the same.
3. Check also user permission of your website.
```

Index Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{       
   return View("~/Views/Home/About.cshtml");
}
```

or

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Good Luck!

Comment: I've done all three... 1. I enabled directory browsing, but it doesn't load the application it just displays a directory tree. 2. The frameworks match. 3. I checked the permissions and they match.

Comment: Did you use the port  like localhost:2345? do you have a default page?if not you need to have a start page.

Comment: You have to register also vb.net in IIS like https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx

Comment: I tried using the port, but it made no difference. I'm using MVC so there isn't a default page and instead a default route. Even having a start page wouldn't have made this work correctly. When IIS sees an expressionless url, as is the case when working with MVC, it looks to the routing table of the MVC engine to see if the engine can return a correctly formatted url then serves the page up to the client. I'm not using visual basic, so registering it with IIS wouldn't have helped much. In this case the fix I posted worked.

Comment: Do you have an index on your home controller? Take a look at the answer above.

Comment: Yeah. Once I removed the PrecompiledApp.config file it started working as expected.

Comment: Are you working in IIS or running the project in your local machine?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133597/discussion-between-innov83r-and-reds).